# Phonegap UDP sockets?

Tags: sockets, cordova, udp, socket.io, phonegap-plugins

Is there, by any chance, possible to setup UDP sockets for a Phonegap app? By any available plugin or such? It has to be compatible with Android and iPhone.

I know TCP are available through Web Sockets, but I need UDP for an app I'm developing (due its speed).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you aware that websocket connections are typically kept open for a long time (often the duration of an app)?  So you won't be bearing the cost of a tcp connection for each message you send.  If you're concerned about the time taken to send a single tcp compared to udp packet, have you tested that this really is significant in your use case?

Comment: I haven't been benchmarking it yet, no, but I'll will :-) But I've had some previous experiences with socket programming. And when it comes to realtime stuff; UDP is better suited, especially for realtime apps/games, which I'm experimenting with currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this maybe work? I'm looking into this issue almost two years after OP but I found chrome's cordova UDP plugin. Don't know anything about it but figured it might help.

https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

It's also NPM compatible...don't know if that matters but https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-sockets-udp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. See [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).